# codename one app walkthrough/tutorial when first open

Tags: codenameone

I want to add a sort-of tutorial feature on my app. Similar to most apps. When the user first opens the app, little popups and dialogs appear which point to and explain the function of each button/element. Is there a way to achieve this in codename one???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is pretty old post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/walk-thru-tutorial.html) that covers a way of doing this with the glasspane. Today I would do something like this using the layered pane but I don't think we created a tutorial for that.

You can use [InteractionDialog](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/InteractionDialog.html) to implement something like that and style it any way you choose.

Comment: I tried to make that kin of tutorial in the layeredPane but I lot of issue. is there the possibilities to have an official tutorial in the foreseeable future?

Comment: I'm pretty busy with upcoming courses so I don't know. We don't have code that does that in any of our apps so there isn't a starting point for a tutorial either. Things change so I don't want to say no, take in mind that we live in startup time and forseeable future is usually next month...